# AspectJ pointcut on all methods of a list of classes

Tags: aop, aspectj, pointcut

I want to log entry to all methods from a list of classes (which could belong from different packages). Note that the methods should belong to the specified classes only.

I've tried the following but these do not work

(1) Using if() pointcut
Here I get an error

```
"incompatible number of arguments to pointcut, expected 1 found 0"

@Pointcut("execution(*.*(..)) && if()")
public static boolean mycut(JoinPoint jp) {
     boolean matches = ... ;//Test using jp if the declaring class belongs to the list
     return matches;
}
```

(2) Using combination of Pointcut and aop.xml
Here I get an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
com.mypackage.TraceAspect.aspectOf()Lcom/df/jc/aspect/TraceAspect;

//in com.mypackage.TraceAspect aspect class
@Pointcut("execution(*.*(..)) && !within(com.mypackage.TraceAspect)")
public void mycut(){
}

//in aop.xml
<weaver>
    <include within="package1.Class1">
    <include within="package2.Class2">
    <include within="package3.Class3">
</weaver>
```

What is going wrong here?

It can of course be done by specifying each class individually in the pointcut, but this is not scalable for hundreds of classes. Ideally, it would be great if the list of classes can be picked up from an external text file (for easy configuration)

Comment: Found this solution, but it would still be better to be able to pick up the required classes from an external file other than aop.xml http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130336/read-aspectj-pointcut-definition-from-property-file-for-ltw

Comment: Why? Is aop.xml not external enough? And BTW, if you have hundreds of classes many of them should have something in common: class name prefix/postfix, package name, implemented interfaces, marker annotations. There are dozens of ways to refactor your code to make it easier to express brief pointcuts instead of maintaining error-prone and usually outdated lists with hundreds of entries. AOP is not meant to patch up bad application design. IMHO your desired way of doing this is a symptom, not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: This is a requirement based on the real world - not all code is good code out there: 
1) There are many packages in the source code (which I want to aspect on) that overlap with packages in some other proprietary Jars (which I don't want to aspect on).

2) The code is legacy, written over many years, with many users - so refactoring is out of question

3) One can argue writing a pre-processor that converts a list of classes into aop.xml, but that introduces two extra steps - a) To run the pre-processor b) To drop aop.xml in correct classpath

4) Just looking for a simple solution in the end

Comment: You use proprietary package names in your own code? Hard to believe. Congratulations. Anyway, you do not need to expose those proprietary JARs to the weaver at all, so they are utterly irrelevant. You want to go for a simple solution? Use the frigging aop.xml! And P.S.: Refactoring legacy code is never out of the question. My agile teams (I am a Scrum coach) do that every day with legacy code. Adding marker annotations and recompiling should be straightforward enough with any decent IDE. But anyway: stop finding a problem in any solution. Start finding a solution for your real-world problem.

Comment: >> You use proprietary package names in your own code? Hard to believe. Congratulations. >> 
This is our own proprietary Jars (not 3rd party). 

>> But anyway: stop finding a problem in any solution. Start finding a solution for your real-world problem.
C'mon! You can either suggest a solution or no solution or don't comment at all. Worst thing you can do is to lecture and discourage people from trying to find a better solution than you had given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your last comment: I am not discouraging you from anything but bad design, I was trying to encourage you to do the right thing: refactor and not make life harder on yourself than necessary. You do not even know the very AspectJ syntax basics and yet you already want to implement an over-complex scenario with tons of classes, which is a maintenance nightmare. I am trying to help by motivating you not to make short-sighted decisions. Believe me, I have been using AspectJ for years in what you call real-life projects with lots of legacy code. Avoiding even the cheapest bit of refactoring is much more expensive than doing smart refactoring - not too much, but enough according to the boy scout rule: leave the camp ground behind cleaner than you found it. It pays off, trust me.

Anyway, talking about your code snippet:

- `execution(*.*(..))` is syntactically wrong because you do not specify a return type (or placeholder for it) for the methods to be matched. You want to use `execution(* *.*(..))` or the shorthand version `execution(* *(..))`.
- The error "incompatible number of arguments to pointcut, expected 1 found 0" does not come from your pointcut but from your advice which you have not even bothered to post. You must have written something like `@Before("mycut()")`, but correct would be  `@Before("mycut(jp)")`.

Having said that, here is a simple, fully self-contained and compileable example:

**Driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(multiply(3, add(4, 5)));
    }

    public static int multiply(int i, int j) { return i * j; }
    public static int add(int i, int j) { return i + j; }
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class TraceAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && if()")
    public static boolean hasMatchingSignature(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        return !thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName().equals("main");
    }

    @Before("hasMatchingSignature(thisJoinPoint)")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.add(int, int))
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.multiply(int, int))
27
```

If your `if()` pointcut would just return `true`, the output would also show the execution of `main`.

Comment: +1, though I have to say that your encouragements sounded more like whip cracking. Advice (aspectL): please think of better wordings next time ;-)

Comment: Thanks @A4L, I have heard you and taken no offense. I know I can be a bit blunt at times, but actually the OP has found the solution of how to externalise his class list (via pom.xml, i.e. an external file as desired) and yet was not content with it, God knows why. pom.xml *is* an external file and even human-readable text. Adding/removing class names there is most trivial. Why does it have to be externalised even further? Where is the benefit or an additional layer of indirection? Anyway, I should stop here.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive answer

Comment: Just FYI, I had 1800 classes. When I used the aop.xml method, I got the following error  

java.io.UTFDataFormatException: encoded string too long: 164785 bytes

Hope now that it makes sense why I was looking for an external file mechanism

Comment: No, it does not. If you really have 1,800+ classes, several groups of them must have something in common, as I said in my first comment under your original posting. You can save a lot of text by using jokers like `my.package..*Controller`or similar. AOP is for cross-cutting concerns the targets of which usually have something in common. I am 99% sure that if I saw your full class list and the ones you crosscut, I could dramatically shorten your pointcuts. Listing every single class is just counterproductive and unmanageable. GO REFACTOR! Don't be a fool with a tool. I mean it in a nice way.

Comment: Ok boss :-) Can you also help with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590662/aspectj-with-weblogic